# Double Quotes in C# String.Format

Tags: c#, string

I want to create a string as shown in the text below :

> 'bookNo':'" + bookNo + "'

My code is

```
String KeyValuePair =
      String.Format("'{0}':'\" + {1} + \"'", key,value);
```

But its not returning exact string as above. What can be done to achieve the same ?

Comment: it is returning that string of course if `value="bookNo"` and `key="bookNo"`, are you checking value in debugger?

Comment: What is your actual output?

Comment: look ok here. What do you get?

Comment: look here http://ideone.com/kELTlJ it's working just fine

Comment: It looks fine to me. Please post your output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know two ways to do it: (I have already tested it)

1) using escape sequences **\"** and **\'**

```
string.Format("\'{0}\':\'\" + {1} + \"\'",key,value);
```

2) using verbatim string character **@**

```
string.Format(@"'{0}':'"" + {1} + ""'",key,value);
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply doing it

```
String key= "BookName";
String value = "BookValue";
String result = String.Format(@"'{0}:' ""+{1}+""", key, value);
```

Comment: @SKpaul you have disappeared after asking ques and other people are discussing on it. not good :(

Comment: Sorry, i was out of desk at my office.